# How to close popovers on modal close?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to close all popovers that are in a modal, so that they are not displayed if I reopen the modal.

The problem is that if I try to close at `$("#modal").on("hidden", function() { [...] });`, the targets are already unavailable. The same goes if I do it at `.on("shown", ...`.

I cannot delete using :

```
$(".buttonPopover").popover("hide");
```

Because `.buttonPopover` is never available at the time I want to delete the popovers. How can I close them all without accessing their parent ?

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/uWieWmHab9)**

Comment: It brokes my modal. ^^ Also, I tried `$(".popover").popover("hide");` and it doesn't work, because the selector should be the target/parent, not the popover element.

Comment: Sorry, and in cibling modal ? :   $('#modal *').popover('hide');  I think you should create a bootply to give a work to answerers....

Comment: Doesn't broke the modal though it doesn't work. I think `.popover()` needs the target/parent selector and it's no more in the modal when I close/reopen it.

Comment: It can be interresting, can you create a bootply.com to have a workspace to play on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that if I try to close at `.on("hidden")`, the targets are already unavailable

That's because the `hidden.bs.modal` event fires:

> "when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete)."

Instead, use the [`hide.bs.modal`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) event which:

> " is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called"

Like this:

```js
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
  $("#openPopover").popover("hide")
});
```

### [Demo in Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/eLWGUzTqYM)

---

#### Update

I'm curious if you're `hidden` event was even firing in the first place.  The event name is namespaced so you have to refer to it as `hidden.bs.modal`

This will never get called:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden', function() {
  alert('hi');
});
```

This should work:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $("#openPopover").popover("hide")
});
```

Comment: I must admit in the case I gave it's working. But in my case, it's giving me an infinite loop and finish with : `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ` after 500+ call to this event. (on the console)

Comment: Well we'd have to know more about your particular code in order to be able to identify what the issue is.  See if you can reproduce it in Bootply and then add it here or mark the complete and start a new question with more specifics.